# Allen Bradley 800 T psd16 c

Tags: electrical

How do I hook up a 800 T Allen Bradley Dule input pilot light on my Ingersoll Rand 220 single phase 7.5 hp compressor

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This seems off-topic for our site, but let's see if you get any good answers.

Comment: What condition do you want this pilot light to show?  Also, can you get us a model number on that compressor?

Comment: It's a model 2340 and I want the light to stay on till I turn the auto switch to off

Answer (score 1):

There should be a diagram right on the label of the pilot light itself.
[image]

The dual inputs is because it is for a system in which you have a common circuit, usually connected to a momentary push button somewhere, that you press to illuminate ALL of the pilot lights at the same time, to test whether or not the lamp is burned out. So (typically) your regular indicator circuit would go to terminal 1, the Test circuit would go to terminal 3 and the common (neutral) would go to terminal 2. There are diodes on 1 and 3 that prevent the circuits from back feeding to each other.

Comment: That diagram doesn't help me at all I need to know where the wires hook up to I want the light to stay on till I turn off the auto switch

Comment: It's single phase it has no neutral wire

Comment: The drawing on the side in that photo shows you exactly where to connect the wires. If you are not using the dual input capability, you just connect to 1 and 2. You must have a neutral if you are using 120V. If you have only 1 wire going to the light, it will not work.